Reason for not taking split brain question off closed?
I have asked the following question whether the split brain experiments demonstrate the mind is not reducible to the brain.  It was closed because I was not clear whether I was asking about consciousness or the conscious mind, which I clarified.  However, the question was not re-opened.  I am requesting the question be re-opened or further advise to improve the question.
Does the split brain disprove a materialistic mind?

Thank you for your dedication to improve the question - it is re-opened and up an running!

Thanks, very much appreciated.  I will do my best to make it a productive question!
